# Exclusive OR in Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, logic

What is the exclusive or functions in scheme? I've tried `xor` and `^`, but both give me an unbound local variable error.

Googling found nothing.

Comment: Do you want bitwise exclusive or?

Comment: I'm working with specifically boolean (#t and #f), so as long as it acts properly on boolean, I'm good

Comment: Actually, I guess not equals works in this case, but I can't figure out what that is either? I tried != and /=

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you use `(not (equal? foo bar))` if not equals works.  Please note that there may be faster comparators for your situiation such as `eq?`

Comment: So Scheme doesn't provide a not equal to function? You have to roll your own with not and (=|eq?|equal?)?

Comment: Scheme is a fairly minimalist language. From R<sup>5</sup>RS: "Programming languages should be designed not by piling feature on top of feature, but by removing the weaknesses and restrictions that make additional features appear necessary." So, there are a lot of things provided by other languages that Scheme merely provides building blocks for. Any given Scheme implementation may provide a more complete library, and the SRFIs http://srfi.schemers.org/ help standardize a few of the extensions to the core language.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can tell from the [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/) (the latest definition of scheme), there is no pre-defined exclusive-or operation.  However, `xor` is equivalent to `not equals` for boolean values so it's really quite easy to define on your own if there isn't a builtin function for it.

Assuming the arguments are restricted to the scheme booleans values `#f` and `#t`,

```
(define (xor a b)
  (not (boolean=? a b)))
```

will do the job.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean bitwise xor of two integers, then each Scheme has it's own name (if any) since it's not in any standard.  For example, PLT has [these bitwise functions](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/numbers.html#%28part._.Bitwise_.Operations%29), including `bitwise-xor`.

(Uh, if you talk about booleans, then yes, `not` & `or` are it...)

Answer (score 6):

Kind of a different style of answer:

```
(define xor
  (lambda (a b)
    (cond
      (a (not b))
      (else b))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading SRFI-1 shed a new light upon my answer. Forget efficiency and simplicity concerns or even testing! This beauty does it all:

```
(define (xor . args)
  (odd? (count (lambda (x) (eqv? x #t)) args)))
```

Or if you prefer:

```
(define (true? x) (eqv? x #t))
(define (xor . args) (odd? (count true? args)))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(define (xor a b)
  (and 
   (not (and a b))
   (or a b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since xor could be used with any number of arguments, the only requirement is that the number of true occurences be odd. It could be defined roughly this way:

```
(define (true? x) (eqv? x #t))

(define (xor . args)
  (odd? (length (filter true? args))))
```

No argument checking needs to be done since any number of arguments (including none) will return the right answer.

However, this simple implementation has efficiency problems: both length and filter traverse the list twice; so I thought I could remove both and also the other useless predicate procedure "true?".

The value odd? receives is the value of the accumulator (aka acc) when args has no remaining true-evaluating members. If true-evaluating members exist, repeat with acc+1 and the rest of the args starting at the next true value or evaluate to false, which will cause acc to be returned with the last count.

```
(define (xor . args)
  (odd? (let count ([args (memv #t args)]
                    [acc 0])
          (if args
              (count (memv #t (cdr args))
                     (+ acc 1))
              acc))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> (define (xor a b)(not (equal? (and a #t)(and b #t))))
> (xor 'hello 'world)
$9 = #f
> (xor #f #f)
$10 = #f
> (xor (> 1 100)(< 1 100))
$11 = #t
```

Answer (score 0):

I revised my code recently because I needed 'xor in scheme and found out it wasn't good enough...

First, my earlier definition of 'true? made the assumption that arguments had been tested under a boolean operation. So I change:

```
(define (true? x) (eqv? #t))
```

... for:

```
(define (true? x) (not (eqv? x #f)))
```

... which is more like the "true" definition of 'true? However, since 'xor returns #t if its arguments have an 'odd? number of "true" arguments, testing for an even number of false cases is equivalent. So here's my revised 'xor:

```
(define (xor . args)
  (even? (count (lambda (x) (eqv? x #f)) args)))
```

Comment: Well, so (even? (count (lambda (x) (eqv? x #f)) '(#t #t #t #f #f)) would return true and (even? (count (lambda (x) (eqv? x #f)) '(#t #t #t #f #f #f)) would return false though both have an odd number of true values... Why should it be equivalent?